# accessing static variable in multi threading system

Tags: java

I have to take one input from console in first java program. That input i have to pass in second java program which is getting executed as thread from the main method of first java program.

I made the variable as static and tried accessing in second java program but it is showing null value(default value).

I am not supposed to make the object of first program also.
Please suggest me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

If your first java program is starting the second using O.S.-like functions that produces the same effect as if you were starting from the console, then you will have a second instance of the JVM, with everything "reseted". That's why you're getting that null.

A suggestion would be passing the value as a parameter for the second program.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no shared memory mechanism implemented in Java. Pipes also don't work across VM boundaries, so you would have to use the JNI and C code to create a mechanism.

But then if the two programs cooperate that close together, why not let them in one VM and use threads? Security reasons is the only thing I could think of.